# Where is "sin_family" in struct sockaddr_in - /usr/include/netinet/in.h?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming, archlinux

I'm new networking socket in c programming. And I'm trying to make a simple sever - client. The following is what I want to have :

```
...
//Binding to a port
struct sockaddr_in name;
name.sin_family = PF_INET;
name.sin_port = (in_port_t)htons(30000);
name.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
...
```

Where is **sin_family - /usr/include/netinet/in.h - Linux** ? If you are a pro, please tell me know what I need to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
struct sockaddr_in
{
  __SOCKADDR_COMMON (sin_);
  in_port_t sin_port;           /* Port number.  */
  struct in_addr sin_addr;      /* Internet address.  */

  /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'.  */
  unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
             __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE -
             sizeof (in_port_t) -
             sizeof (struct in_addr)];
};
```

You see there is a `__SOCKADDR_COMMON(sin_)` in `sockaddr_in` structure which is a macro. 
now lets see the macro defination in **/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/bits/sockaddr.h**:

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON(sa_prefix) \
sa_family_t sa_prefix##family
```

and

```
#define __SOCKADDR_COMMON_SIZE  (sizeof (unsigned short int))
```

so ultimately `sockaddr_in` is expanded to:

```
struct sockaddr_in
{
  sa_family_t sin_family;
  in_port_t sin_port;           /* Port number.  */
  struct in_addr sin_addr;      /* Internet address.  */

  /* Pad to size of `struct sockaddr'.  */
  unsigned char sin_zero[sizeof (struct sockaddr) -
             (sizeof (unsigned short int) -
             sizeof (in_port_t) -
             sizeof (struct in_addr)];
};
```

This is how `sin_family` comes in `sockaddr_in` .